# IBMCloud - How can I connect to MongoDB?

Tags: mongoid

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB in a IBMCloud instance and I'm using MongoID. I ever use some configurations and try very things. I'm getting the error:

```
MONGODB | Error running ismaster on address:port: system lib
```

Here is my mongoid.yml that I'm trying to connect to mongoDB:

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: databasename
      hosts:
        - address:port
        - address:port
      options:
        user: 'admin'
        password: 'some-password'
        auth_mech: :scram
        auth_source: admin
        connect: :replica_set
        replica_set: replset
        ssl: true
        ssl_ca_cert: ./some-certificate.pem
        ssl_verify: true
  options:
    log_level: :debug
```

What do I need to add to connect with the mongo database in IBMCloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"system lib" is coming from OpenSSL and indicates a problem with the CA certificate, such as the path not referring to an existing file. Note that in the configuration you specified a relative path which could cause problems.

I created https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-1946 to add the exception class to the reported message which would clarify where the error is originating in the future.

Upgrade to the current version of Ruby driver (2.10.2 as of this writing) which provides more extensive diagnostics. Set driver log level to debug (https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#logging). If you are having trouble identifying the problem then, post the 
updated error and log messages here.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I think this is the error: No primary server is available in cluster

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I think this is the log:Failed to handshake with url: Mongo::Error::SocketError: EOFError: end of file reached (for IP (no TLS))

Comment: "system lib" is coming from OpenSSL and indicates an issue with the CA certificate, for which I updated the answer. EOFError shows that the connection is attempted without TLS which is inconsistent with the configuration you provided in the question, but is the expected behavior when you are trying to connect to a TLS server without TLS enabled in the driver.